# which is the best flow of using both the sql database and web service data?

Tags: android, database

we have making media player that play the media files from server.in my current flow we are get the server response in json format, then we store that data in database and again it store in array list and after that it is display by custom list everything is in working mode. but i m not happy with flow. pls anybody suggest me good flow. or any peturn

Comment: mention how many entries you got in your list

Answer (score 0):

If the list is large, you can use CursorAdapter to back your list. That way you will not have to bother about re-loading/refreshing the list every time there is a database write.